# Action already returned but browser not fetching results

Tags: c#, browser, asp.net-mvc-4, lag, jsonresult

In ASP.NET MVC 4, I have a [HttpGet] action method, that returns a JsonResponse.

```
    public JsonResult List(int domainId)
    {
            ....
    }
```

When I call this method with the browser, by typing the URL: localhost:43229/GroupsAjax/List?domainId=1, I have to wait like 50 seconds to see the results.

My first thought was that the method was too slow, but by adding breakpoints I noticed that it already had returned.

[image: Breakpoints]

I tried with Iexplorer too and the same lag happend.
In chrome, the lag was associated with the "Waiting time", according to the timeline

**What might be happening?**

Comment: What does this have to do with AJAX?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right. Its not directly associated but I want to use this URL with ajax.

Comment: Aha. I don't think it is directly related to this problem. You might want to include the tags [tag:asp.net-mvc-4] and [tag:C#].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reviewing old questions (by me) without answers, the answer to this is/was:

I should have included the AsJson() code:

```
    public dynamic AsJson()
    {
        return new
        {
           name = this.Name,
           membersCount = this.Members.Count()
        }
    }
```

The query was this:

```
 dynamic results = from g in groups.ToList()
                   select g.AsJson();
```

The "this.Members.Count()" is run in memory because of the ToList().

So: the query is divided in to parts: **SQL To Entities** and **SQL To Objects**

The first part was fast, the second was slow (has to do Members.Count() N times, being N the number of results in "groups.ToList()"